# How to stop javascript errors from opening windows in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms

I have a webBrowser  control that is used in the backend to navigate some sites. This is never actually shown to the user.

However, some sites have broken javascript and that causes a window to pop-up with the continue script or stop. The page still works, but I don't want this window to show up.

Besides removing the javascript at runtime from the page, is there anything else I can do to suppress them?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to answer my own question, found on another forum.

```
webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```